# Mysql select statements based on different conditions

Tags: mysql, express

I am currently writing a project tracker, with which it is possible to create projects. As soon as a project is created, it is automatically public. However, you can edit the project and my node js backend set the "is_private" flag to 1 = true. Now I also have various queries where e.g. a search term will be entered. If the current user is the project author, this should be shown in the ajax live search, but not for everyone else.

in pseudo code that means

```
if (mysql.table.project.is_private === 1 && 
    mysql.table.project.person_id ===  req.session.person.personId) {
    showProjectsOnlyForProjectAuthor ()
} else if (is_private === 0) {
    showAllProjects ()
}
```

How can this be translated as a mysql query? I think I have to do two different queries based on two conditions

This is my current query, which shows all public projects

```
SELECT * 
FROM project_tracker_dev.project 
WHERE (project.is_private = 0) 
  AND (title LIKE "%searchTerm%" OR description LIKE "%searchTerm%") ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM project_tracker_dev.project 
WHERE 
(
      is_private = 0 OR
     (is_private = 1 AND person_id = $personId)
)
AND (title LIKE "%project%" OR description LIKE "%project%") ;
```